# JS: How to convert from string to enum to map key?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, enums

Snippet:

```
enum Color {
    RED = 0,
    GREEN
}

const myMap = new Map<Color, string>([
    [Color.GREEN, "foo"],
    [Color.RED, "bar"]
])


const red_s = "RED"
const myColor: Color = red_s as unknown as Color
console.log(`myColor ${myColor}`)

const mapVal = myMap.get(myColor)
if (mapVal) {
    console.log(`mapVal ${mapVal}`)
}
else {
    console.log(`no mapVal found`)
}
```

Why is the enum `myColor` not found in `myMap`?

How can I use the enum as a key for the map?

Comment: `Color.GREEN` is `1` and `Color.RED` is `0`, they're not the strings `"GREEN"` and `"RED"`. You'll see that if you log these values or your `Map`.`Color[Color.RED]` is `"RED"`

Comment: @NickParsons: I do not pass a string to .get(). The type of myColor is Color. And the map is declared with keys of type Color. How can I make this work?

Comment: [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74640873/5648954) explains what's going on well and how it can be fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as` keyword only tells the compiler to treat a variable as a certain type. It does not actually change the underlying type. If you run a typeof check, you will see myColor is a string, not Color:

```
const red_s = "RED"
const myColor: Color = red_s as unknown as Color
console.log(`${typeof myColor}`) // Prints string
```

To set red_s as an enum, you need to do:

```
const red_s: Color = Color["RED"];
```

Comment: Thank you. It is really confusing if we declare myColor with type Color, but really it is not.

Comment: No problem. The compiler would have thrown an error when you initially tried to cast `red_s as Color`. But then you added the `as unknown` to get around the error. This should generally be avoided!